# How to validate email addresses using vuelidate?

Tags: vuelidate, vetur

### How to validate emails?

Would you please show an example with an error message?

Documentation does not give enough details.

It seems there is nothing like `v-if="!$v.user.email.email"`

**Following code does not work either**

```js
validations: {
 user: {
  email: {
        required,
        email: email(),
      },
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actualy, I was wrong and  **there was** something like `v-if="!$v.user.email.email"`
You do not need any details for email validator.

All you need is

```
 email: {
        email,
      },
```

**If you had any Vetur errors just uninstall Vetur and reinstall it.**

```js
Vue.use(window.vuelidate.default)
const { email } = window.validators

new Vue({
    el: "#app",
  data: {
    user: {
     email: ""
    }
  },
  validations: {
    user:{
        email: {
          email
        }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    status(validation) {
        return {
        error: validation.$error,
        dirty: validation.$dirty
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
input {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.dirty {
  border-color: #5A5;
  background: #EFE;
}

.error {
  border-color: red;
  background: #FDD;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/combine/npm/vuelidate@0.7.5/dist/validators.min.js,npm/vuelidate@0.7.5/dist/vuelidate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="$v.user.email.$model" :class="status($v.user.email)">
   <div class="error" v-if="!$v.user.email.email">this must be an email</div>
  <pre>{{ $v }}</pre>
</div>
```

---

Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61359412/11993949 shows off how to use *on blur* functionality too

Answer (score 0):

you can use this regex validation pattern to validate your email.

```
 [a-zA-Z0-9]&#x2B;@[a-z]&#x2B;\.[a-z]{2,3}
```

If you are getting as json format you can try this

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]&#x2B;@[a-z]&#x2B;\\.[a-z]{2,}
```